# Yandex касса: Response is not XML/HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmlhttprequest, httpwebrequest, яндекс-касса

Есть Api написанное на C# для взаимодействия с яндекс кассой, после того как со стороны сервера приходит запрос на проверку заказа, я должен сформировать ответ и отослать обратно яндексу, ответ должен быть в виде xml файла. Все сделал как мне кажется верно, но приходит ошибка см. заголовок поста.

Вот реализация сборки ответа в виде xml

```
public XmlDocument BuildResponse(
       string functionName,
       long invoiceId,
       long resultCode,
       string message
       )
    {
        try
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            var performedDatetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffK");
            var xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            var root = doc.DocumentElement;
            doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);

            var funcElem = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, functionName + "Response", string.Empty);
            doc.AppendChild(funcElem);

            var dateAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("performedDatetime");
            dateAttr.Value = performedDatetime.ToString();
            funcElem.SetAttributeNode(dateAttr);

            var codeAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("code");
            codeAttr.Value = resultCode.ToString();
            funcElem.SetAttributeNode(codeAttr);

            var msgAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("message");
            msgAttr.Value = (message != null) ? message : "";
            funcElem.SetAttributeNode(msgAttr);

            var invoiceIdAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("invoiceId");
            invoiceIdAttr.Value = invoiceId.ToString();
            funcElem.SetAttributeNode(invoiceIdAttr);

            var shopIdTextAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("shopId");
            shopIdTextAttr.Value = Settings.SHOP_ID.ToString();
            funcElem.SetAttributeNode(shopIdTextAttr);

            return doc;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Вот отправка полученного ответа

```
 private string SendResponse(XmlDocument responseBody)
    {
        string host = @"https://demomoney.yandex.ru/eshop.xml";

        var contentType = "xml";
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = $"application/{contentType}";
            request.Accept = $"application/{contentType}";

            var postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseBody.InnerXml);
            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

            using (Stream putStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                putStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            }

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Response from Yandex: " + reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
            return null;                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return e.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Сформированный XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><checkOrderResponse performedDatetime="2017-09-07T16:38:19.343+03:00" code="0" message="" invoiceId="1111" shopId="111" />
```

Пожалуйста объясните мне в чем может быть ошибка, или может мои глаза уже замылены и я не вижу косяка в коде. 
Заранее всем отвечающим спасибо за ваше участие в решении вопроса

Comment: самый простой способ - это посмотреть как выглядит XML который вы отправляете, неплохо бы добавить его в вопрос. Скорее всего нарушена структура. Я обычно формирую XML в другом порядке: сначала `var root = newXElement("rootName");`, весь контент в root, а в самом конце `new XDocument(declaraton, root);`. Проблем ни разу не было

Comment: @rdorn XML добавил в вопрос

Comment: @rdorn можете пример кода, того как вы формируете скинуть?

Comment: да нет, приведенный вами XML вполне корректен. Разве что попробовать убрать декларацию [тут](https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/payment-solution/payment-notifications/payment-notifications-check-docpage/) она не указана в примере ответа.

Comment: @rdorn в итоге сформировал xml тем способом что вы сказали, результат тот же, способ гораздо удобнее, за инфу спасибо

Comment: @rdorn вот без декларации как раз используя XDocument сделал, результат тот же

Comment: не за что, LiNQtoXML значительно удобнее старого тяжеловесного XmlDocument, а возможности те же. Больше, к сожалению не знаю чем помочь, может стоит потрясти поддержку яндекса. По их же документации вроде бы все правильно, но, в целом, не слишком понятно

Comment: @rdorn ТП яндекса меня очень удивила, там сидят люди которые не различают get и post запросы, как им это пытаться объяснить даже и представить не могу.
Ну спасибо вам большое за внимание и за некий экспириенс, что-то новое узнал)

Comment: стоп. все правильно, вы не должны посылать этот XML сами. Вы должны его отдать, когда касса обратится по указанному для проверки  URL. У вас же WEB приложение? Меня смущает Console.WriteLine

Comment: @rdorn по сути консолька, api которое обрабатывает запросы с мобилок и сайтов.Так сначала касса то и обращается со стороны яндекса, я делаю тестовоую форму в виде html или с мобилки кидаю тестовый платеж с тестовыми данными, яндекс проверяет введенные данные банковской карты shopid, scid, paymenttype, формирует дополнительные входные параметры типа md5 итд, потом мне приходит со стороны яндекс кассы запрос, я делаю проверку и как результат проверки должен отправить в ответ респонз со статусом проверки

Comment: смотрите - когда вы обращаетесь к некоторому URL, сервер отдает вам html страницу, сформированную web-приложением. В вашем случае нужно точно такое же поведение, только вместо html должен формироваться xml. А у вас сейчас получается, что вы запрос получили, а вместо ответа, отправляете встречный запрос

Comment: @rdorn если не сложно можете в коде правку сделать чтобы был наглядный пример, пока не догоняю что именно надо поправить

Comment: сложно, т.к. я не вижу в приведенном коде фрагмента, который получает запрос от кассы.... Есть только код отправки встречного запроса, использование `WebRequest` как-бы намекает

Comment: @rdorn просто к обычному mvc шному контроллеру кидается POST запрос со стороны яндекса, параметры передаются в строке запроса я их принимаю и начинаю с ними работать.
Т.е. метод с атрибутом [HttpPost("checkOrder")]

Comment: ну вот контроллер и должен формировать ответ, так же, как если бы отвечал за переход на другую страницу сайта. Он может обратиться к вашей консольке за готовым ответом, но отправлять ответ должен сам.

Comment: вместо кода отправки из консоли, лучше приложите код action-метода из контроллера, который обрабатывает запрос от кассы. Исправлять нужно именно его.

Comment: @rdorn вам огромное спасибо!!!! Все получилось, тестовая оплата прошла

Comment: отлично, тогда попробую оформить ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Краткое резюме обсуждения в комментариях:

Ошибка заключается в том, что вместо ответа на внешний запрос вы посылаете встречный запрос.

Согласно документации, API Яндекс.Кассы устроен таким образом, что касса сама обращается к сайту магазина по зарегистрированному в ней URL и ждет, в качестве ответа, указанный вами XML.

Т.е. ответ, в данном случае, должен отдавать web-сервер, в случае приложения MVC - с помощью `return` в соответствующем action-методе контроллера. Внешнее приложение может быть использовано только для формирования XML, но не для передачи ответа.

---

Для работы с XML более удобно и наглядно использовать LiNQtoXML. Пример для формирования вашего XML:

```
var responseXml = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("checkOrderResponse",
        new XAttribute("performedDatetime", "2017-09-07T16:38:19.343+03:00"),
        new XAttribute("code", 0),
        new XAttribute("message", ""),
        new XAttribute("invoiceId", 1111),
        new XAttribute("shopId", 111)
    )
);
//получаем сформированный XML в виде текста
var responseText = responseXml.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

благодарю всех за ответы!

выкладываю еще один вариант кода без проверки подлинности платежа (об этом много написано)
надеюсь кому то будет полезно ))

Код формы

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Secured Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form_main" action="https://demomoney.yandex.ru/eshop.xml" method="post" lang="en" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input name="shopId" value="ваш ид" type="hidden"/>
            <input name="scid" value="ваш ид" type="hidden"/>
            <input name="customerNumber" value="Покупатель N1"/>
            <input name="sum" value="10.00"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Оплатить"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Код Хендлера

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using  System.Xml.Linq;

public class ssl_yandex_kassa : IHttpHandler {

    HttpContext context     = null;
    int shop_id             = ваш ид;
    long invoice_id         = 0;

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext m_context) {
        context     = m_context;
        invoice_id  = Convert.ToInt64(context.Request.Form["invoiceId"]);

        switch(context.Request.Form["action"])
        {
                case "checkOrder":
                    SendResponse(BuildResponse("checkOrder", invoice_id, 0));
                    break;
                case "paymentAviso":
                    SendResponse(BuildResponse("paymentAviso", invoice_id, 0));
                    break;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.QueryString["success"]))
            context.Response.Write("success: " + context.Request.QueryString["success"]);
    }

    public string BuildResponse(string prefix, long invoice_id, long status_code)
    {
        try
        {
            var responseXml = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement( prefix + "Response",
                new XAttribute("performedDatetime", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffK")),
                new XAttribute("code", status_code),
                new XAttribute("invoiceId", invoice_id),
                new XAttribute("shopId", shop_id)
            ));

            return responseXml.Declaration.ToString() + responseXml.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void SendResponse(string body)
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType        = "application/xml";
        context.Response.ContentEncoding    = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        context.Response.Write(body);
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.Close();
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```